What are common reasons for stock photography sites to reject submissions?
I'm encountering numerous errors when trying to submit my photos to various stock websites, and the error messages I receive are often confusing and unclear. Can someone help me understand the common reasons for photo submission rejections on stock sites and provide some guidance on how to address these issues effectively?

Please include at least one error you have received! As it stands, this question is akin to asking... My print-outs are no good. How do I fix it?

Most stock agencies have guidelines for submissions.
This is just a small excerpt from those ShutterStock guidelines; it goes into much more detail...

Photo submissions must pass a series of checks to be acceptable for either creative or data licensing, or both:
When a photo meets all legal, compliance, metadata, and quality
requirements, it will be made available for both creative and data licensing unless a contributor opts out of data licensing.
When a photo meets all legal, compliance, and metadata requirements but fails to meet the minimum quality requirements, the content will only be accepted for data licensing.
When a photo fails to meet legal, compliance, and/or metadata requirements or an egregious quality issue is found, the content will be rejected and will not be accepted into our marketplace.

